# I need help in making the JS event loop wait for a functions execution

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in which I use fabric.js

- I take image address from database.
- Replace a placeholder image on the canvas.
- And then save the canvas as a PNG with ajax.

When I run this code and console log index at different points I saw that the main loop runs through and after that Image replacement part logs index and even later ajax is done.

pseudocode

```
    for loop
    {
        console.log("start");

        // To go through the image addresses array retrieved from database

        for loop
        {
            console.log("Inside Second loop");

            // To Go through placeholder images or layer of images 
            // There can be multiple images on canvas to replace
            
            // replace Image happens here

            console.log("BeforeImageChange");
            imgToChange.setSrc(imgAddressFromDB){
                console.log("AfterImageChange");
            }
        }
        
        function saveCanvas(){
            //function to save canvas as a Image done through ajax to php
            console.log("AfterSaving");
        }

        saveCanvas();
        console.log("End");
    }
```

console.log output is like

```
    "start"
    "Inside Second loop"
    "BeforeImageChange"
    "End"
    "AfterImageChange"
    "AfterSaving"
```

How can I make it so AfterImageChange happens right after BeforeImageChange and Saving happens before loop end?

I am new to javascript, I tried learning about asynchronous methods but they aren't making sense to me that if they are useful in my case. If you need more information comment below. Thanks

Comment: you'll need to deal with the pseudo asynchrony that is present in the pseudo function that pseudo saves the pseudo image to your pseudo server

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for the advice, but I am already doing that, the first loop is to iterate through the array of image addresses. The second loop is because the canvas could have multiple placeholder images to replace so to go through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-arrange your code. You already know the answer because you know how the code behave but perhaps you're not familiar with the techniques. Firstly you need to do this:

```
for loop
{
    console.log("start");

    // To go through the image address retrieved from database

    for loop
    {
        console.log("Inside Second loop");

        // To Go through placeholder images or layer of images
        // replace Image happens here

        console.log("BeforeImageChange");
        imgToChange.setSrc(imgAddressFromDB){
            console.log("AfterImageChange");

            // You already know that code inside here
            // gets executed last
    
            function saveCanvas(){
                //function to save canvas as a Image done through ajax to php
                console.log("AfterSaving");
            }

            saveCanvas();
            console.log("End");
        }
    }
}
```

But I presume you don't want to `saveCanvas()` on each iteration of the loop. Therefore you need to execute it only on the completion of the last `setSrc()`:

```
for loop
{
    console.log("start");

    // To go through the image address retrieved from database

    let setSrcCount = figureOutHowManyTimesTheForLoopBelowLoops();

    for loop
    {
        console.log("Inside Second loop");

        console.log("BeforeImageChange");
        imgToChange.setSrc(imgAddressFromDB){
            console.log("AfterImageChange");

            setSrcCount --;

            if (setSrcCount === 0) {
                function saveCanvas(){
                    //function to save canvas as a Image done through ajax to php
                    console.log("AfterSaving");
                }

                saveCanvas();
                console.log("End");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code can be made more readable if you use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
function setSrc(imgAddress) {
    return new Promise((ok,err) => {
        imgToChange.setSrc(imgAddress,function () {
            ok();
        });
    });
}

async function functionContainingLoops() {

  for loop
  {
    console.log("start");

    // To go through the image address retrieved from database

    for loop
    {
        console.log("Inside Second loop");

        // To Go through placeholder images or layer of images
        // replace Image happens here

        console.log("BeforeImageChange");

        await setSrc(imgAddressFromDB);

        console.log("AfterImageChange");
    }

    function saveCanvas(){
        //function to save canvas as a Image done through ajax to php
        console.log("AfterSaving");
    }

    saveCanvas();
    console.log("End");
  }
}

ContainingLoops()
```

Comment: Thanks, the code with promises solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling **saveCanvas()** inside the **setSrc** method, this way saveCanvas will be called after calling AfterSaving console.

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work properly as there can be multiple images on canvas the second loop is to go through them to replace them, so if I move function call inside setSrc it will replace one image and save it, saveCanvas must execute after second loop.